# Hide 'successfully added to cart' message

Tags: 7, commerce

I use commerce checkout on a Drupal site but it is primarily an information site. So I effectively want to hide the cart from the user.

This means that on addition of a product to the cart, I want to remove the Drupal message *'Product' added to your cart*.

This can't just be hidden in CSS because we want other checkout messages to still be visible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's just set by a rule called "Display an Add to Cart message".

You should be able to delete/disable that rule in the UI and the message will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

@Clives's answer is correct and for those looking for Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V

```
/**
 * Disable adding to the cart the messages.
 */
function HOOK_update_7000() {
  $rules_config = rules_config_load('commerce_cart_add_to_cart_message');
  $rules_config->active = FALSE;
  $rules_config->save();
}
```

Comment: where would be the best place to put this code?

Comment: @AaronAffleck Welcome to Drupal Answers!  I converted your answer to a comment until you have enough rep to comment directly.  [`hook_update_N()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x) functions go in a mymodule.install file.  It's can't go in a theme, and not a .module file, just a .install for one of our modules.